# NIFI:getting data from xml (Evaluate Xpath)?

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-nifi

I have  xml response  similar  to  this  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DayInfo>
<TalkMessage 
        xmlns="***">
        <EnvelopeVersion>**</EnvelopeVersion>
        <Header>
            <MessageDetails>
                <Class>****</Class>
                <Qualifier>*****</Qualifier>
                <Function>***</Function>
                <CorrelationID>*****</CorrelationID>
                <ResponseEndPoint />
            </MessageDetails>
            <SenderDetails>
                <IDAuthentication />
                <EmailAddress />
            </SenderDetails>
        </Header>
        <TalkDetails></TalkDetails>

         <Body>
         with message like
         <person><../person>
         <contact>...</contact>
         <data>... </data>

         </Body>
         </DayInfo>
```

and in my evaluateXpath processors  i want to  extract data  so that i  got  3  different  xml file  with three different message data i used expressions  like this  :**//*[local-name()='person']**  for  each messages and i got  xml  response  with only person data  but i need  this  data  in my  xml too:

```
<TalkMessage 
        xmlns="***">
        <EnvelopeVersion>**</EnvelopeVersion>
        <Header>
            <MessageDetails>
                <Class>****</Class>
                <Qualifier>*****</Qualifier>
                <Function>***</Function>
                <CorrelationID>*****</CorrelationID>
                <ResponseEndPoint />
            </MessageDetails>
            <SenderDetails>
                <IDAuthentication />
                <EmailAddress />
            </SenderDetails>
        </Header>
        <TalkDetails></TalkDetails>
```

what should i change to get  appropriate  response(i mean person message data  with TalkMessage data)?
good  reponse example for person message is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DayInfo>
<TalkMessage 
        xmlns="***">
        <EnvelopeVersion>**</EnvelopeVersion>
        <Header>
            <MessageDetails>
                <Class>****</Class>
                <Qualifier>*****</Qualifier>
                <Function>***</Function>
                <CorrelationID>*****</CorrelationID>
                <ResponseEndPoint />
            </MessageDetails>
            <SenderDetails>
                <IDAuthentication />
                <EmailAddress />
            </SenderDetails>
        </Header>
        <TalkDetails></TalkDetails>

         <Body>

         <person>
         <id></id>
         <name></name>
         </person>


         </Body>
         </DayInfo>
```

Comment: should  i use  replace Text  for this?

Comment: Could you attach the entire example of your target response you are going to get?

Comment: I  have eddited  post and added  it too

Answer (score 0):

If you have an opportunity to use xsl transformation, I would recommend the following transform

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Body">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="person"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only children of the Body element are:

- person
- contact
- data

Instead of the xpath:

```
//*[local-name()='person']
```

Try selecting all the desired elements except the contact and data elements:

```
//*[local-name()!='contact' and local-name()!='data']
```